# VueJS - How to pass function to global component

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have a confirm dialog, which should be shown when users perform delete action. I need to make it works globally (Many pages can use this component by passing confirm message and delete function to it). However, I haven't found a way to pass a function to this component. 
**Thanks in advance!**

ConfirmDialog component:

```html
<template>
  <v-dialog
    v-model="show"
    persistent
    max-width="350"
  >
    <v-card>
      <v-card-text class="text-xs-center headline lighten-2" primary-title>
        {{ message }}
      </v-card-text>
      <v-card-actions class="justify-center">
        <v-btn color="back" dark @click="close">キャンセル</v-btn>
        <v-btn color="primary" dark>削除</v-btn>
      </v-card-actions>
    </v-card>
  </v-dialog>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      show: false,
      message: ''
    }
  },
  created: function () {
    this.$store.watch(state => state.confirmDialog.show, () => {
      const msg = this.$store.state.confirmDialog.message
      if (msg !== '') {
        this.show = true
        this.message = this.$store.state.confirmDialog.message
      } else {
        this.show = false
        this.message = ''
      }
    })
  },
  methods: {
    close () {
      this.$store.commit('closeDialog')
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

ConfirmDialog store:

```js
export default {
  state: {
    show: false,
    message: '',
    submitFunction: {}
  },
  getters: {
  },
  mutations: {
    showDialog (state, { message, submitFunction }) {
      state.show = true
      state.message = message
      state.submitFunction = submitFunction
    },
    closeDialog (state) {
      state.show = false
      state.message = ''
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Phil for updating my question!

Comment: Syntax highlighting makes HTML blocks in particular easier to read. Happy to help

Comment: Use mixin property. Or make a delete component as a shared component and import it in every component and pass the data to it. Mixins in vuejs: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html

Answer (score 0):

you can get and set states easily.

try getting the value of `show` with `...mapState`

ConfirmDialog.vue :

```
<template>
  <v-dialog
    v-if="show"
    persistent
    max-width="350"
  >
    <v-card>
      <v-card-text class="text-xs-center headline lighten-2" primary-title>
        {{ message }}
      </v-card-text>
      <v-card-actions class="justify-center">
        <v-btn color="back" dark @click="close">キャンセル</v-btn>
        <v-btn color="primary" dark>削除</v-btn>
      </v-card-actions>
    </v-card>
  </v-dialog>
</template>

<script>
import { mapState } from 'vuex';
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      show: false,
      message: ''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    close () {
      this.$store.commit('closeDialog')
    }
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapState({
      show: 'show'
    })
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: I would need to pass a function to pass a dialog component.

Answer (score 0):

The store is, as the name says, a store. You have a centralized tree where you save data, not functionalities. Another reason is that functions are not serializable.

You could create this component in a global way by injecting the function as prop or by using `emit` and handling the functionality in the parent.